# Why the key event causes snappy transitions?

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

I can't understand why two quick **button** clicks cause the div shown to transition slowly from its last position to the initial position (as I want) but two quick **key events** to make it *snap* to the initial position.

In the following code, the button click and a window key event initially transition the div to the right by 500px. On the next firing, they take it back to its original position. Quick firing will cause the div to quickly go to some position on the right and come back again.

With two button clicks I face no problem. But with two quick right-arrow key clicks I notice *snappy behaviour*. Any suggestions will really be appreciated, because I couldn't find any explanation to this strange behaviour.

```js
var ele = document.getElementById("f");
var key = true;
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button")
var counter = 0;
var c = [0,500];

function demo() {
    counter = !counter + 0;
    navigateSlider();
}

// code to account for KEY
if (key) {
   window.onkeydown = function (e) {
      console.log(e.keyCode);      
      if (e.keyCode == 39) {
         buttons[0].click();
      }
   }
}

function navigateSlider() {
   ele.style.transition = "1s ease";
   ele.style.transform = "translateX(" + c[counter] + "px)";
}
```

```html
<div id="f" style="background-color: grey; border-radius: 10px;border: 1px solid black; padding: 50px;display: inline-block"></div>
<br><br>
<button onclick="demo()">Go Right</button>
```

Comment: IE11 for once does it right

Comment: Also using 'keyup' makes it way less jolty

Comment: But what if I need to use the keydown event

Comment: You can use 'keydown' see my answer below. I was trying to narrow down causes of this behavior and I found that 'keyup' is less affected. So it must be some inner browser action related to 'keydown' event that blocks animation.

Comment: I don't know if other people can check out the edits of a question, but if you check out one of the snippets in the edits of this question it is working perfectly, with the same code as above.

Comment: Question was edited by 'Temani Afif' but code snippet contained has the same problem you asked about

Answer (score 0):

Can't say exactly why but if you trigger click event with '0' timeout it works better.

```
if (e.keyCode == 39) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        buttons[0].click();
    }, 0);
}
```

It definitely seems handling keyboard events somehow interrupts CSS transitions in Chrome and Firefox.